# empty file when upload a mediaObject

Tags: php, html, reactjs, symfony

When I try to upload a file on my Symfony API, I have an error from MediaObjectAction.php which is a controller.
This file looks like this :

```
final class CreateMediaObjectAction extends AbstractController
{    
     public function __invoke(Request $request): MediaObject
    {
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required');
        }

        $mediaObject = new MediaObject();
        $mediaObject->file = $uploadedFile;

        return $mediaObject;
    }
}
```

and it throws me the error : **"file" is required**

In the front-end, I use ReactJS and I do a simple file upload with these functions :

```
  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0])
    setFile({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0], loaded: 0 })
  }

  const uploadFile = () => {
    FileUtils.uploadFile(MEDIA_OBJECT_ENDPOINT, file.selectedFile)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
```

```
const FileUtils = {
  uploadFile: async (url, file) => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('name', 'file')
    data.append('file', file)
    const response = await api.post(url, data)
    return response
  },
}
```

And in html, the file input looks like this :

```
<input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        name="file"
        onChange={handleFileChange}
      ></input>
```

As you can see, it is very basic, but it does not work and I cannot figure out why. Do you have an idea of what I miss ?

PS : The function api.post() works very well, the problem does not come from it.